# how to separate images in a folder to train folder according to the filename in my train csv file

Tags: python, deep-learning

currently learning deep learning with my own dataset
and have around 70k images in 1 folder
and already input the images to csv file that have `filename, width, height, class` and already divide them randomly into `train,valid, and test csv`

my question is,
is there any way how to seperate the images based on the filename on my csv files?

any answer would be appreciated <3
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to extract the values from a column from the data frame and save them in a list

```
      filenames = data['filenames'].values
      filenames = filenames.tolist()
      classes = data['classes'].values
      classes = classes.tolist()
```

Now, Extract the file names from the directory  **"C:/data/Images/"** or use **os.getcwd()**

```
     path = os.getcwd()
     images = [imagefilename for imagefilename in os.listdir(path) if imagefilename.endswith('.jpg') or imagefilename.endswith('.png')]
```

Now, compare the **images** and **filename**

```
  finalclasses = []
  finalimages = []
  for i in range(len(filename)):
       if len(images) != len(filenames): break;
       if filename[i] == images[i]:
            finalclasses.append(classes[i])
            finalimages.append(os.path.join(path, image)) #or read with opencv by importing cv2   finalimages.append(cv2.read(os.path.join(path, image)))
```

The above will helps to solve your problem, Thank, Happy Learning :)

Comment: woah its work thank you so much !, sorry i cant upvote for now need some more points to upvote:( but thank you !